# Flask возврат на защищенную страницу

Tags: flask

Есть работающее веб-приложение с возможностью входа в личный кабинет.

[image]

Когда пользователь вводит корректный логин и пароль, то при помощи вот этой функции:

```
@app.route('/personal_account', methods=['POST'])
def welcome():
    login = request.form['login']
    password = request.form['password']
    if not validate_user(login, password):
        return jsonify({'success': False})

    user = User()
    user.id = login
    login_user(user)
    data = get_user_data(login)
    # g.login = login
    trigger_logged_id()
    return render_sidebar_template("personal_account.html", data=data)
```

пользователь может попасть в личный кабинет. В данный момент, когда это случается, на сайте появляется дополнительная кнопка 'Personal account'.

[image]

Управление сессией логинизации/разлогинизации происходит при помощи расширения flask-login.

Я хочу прикрутить новую фичу, идея которой заключается в следующем: если пользователь ходит по сайту, по разным html страницам, он может в любой момент при желании вернуться в свой личный кабинет 
Например, будучи на странице About page вернуться в personal account.

[image]

В данный момент, если юзер уходит и потом нажимает на Personal account, то получает ошибку `Method not allowed`. Я не знаю, как это имплементировать, потому что переход на страницу личного кабинета - это POST запрос, и кроме того переход туда защищен функцией `validate_user()`.

Можно было бы сделать глобальный словарь, куда сохранялся бы каждый пользователь, который вошел, но это не кажется оптимальным решением, в этом случае придется все время вызывать функцию `get_user_data()`.

Как сделать корректный возврат в личный кабинет в моем случае, имея ввиду, что сервер должен выдерживать много запросов в минуту?

Comment: а почему не хотите хранить всю информацию в session?